# Can you explain why this code produce gradient as None?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I want to get gradient of parameter with pytorch's autogradient system. However, my code fails to make gradient.
I think autograd fails when i use functions, but it would be too long when i don't use many custom functions. How should i change this code?
My specific code is like below. Thank you

```
import torch as T
import numpy as np

n_qubits=6
device=T.device('cuda:0' if T.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
m=3
s=np.zeros((2**m,1))
s[0]=1
M=np.kron(np.identity(2**(n_qubits-m)),np.matmul(s,np.transpose(s)))
M=T.tensor(M,dtype=T.cfloat).to(device)

def RX(theta,q):
    return T.kron(T.eye(2**int(q),dtype=T.cfloat).to(device),
                  T.kron(T.matrix_exp(-0.5*theta*T.complex(T.zeros(2,2),
                   T.tensor(np.array([[0,1],[1,0]]),dtype=T.float)).to(device)),
                     T.eye(2**(n_qubits-int(q)-1),dtype=T.cfloat).to(device))).to(device)
def f(theta,ro_train):
    return T.trace(T.real(T.mm(M,T.mm(RX(theta,0),T.mm(ro_train,RX(-theta,0)))))).to(device)

theta=T.tensor(1,dtype=T.float,requires_grad=True).to(device)
ro_train=T.tensor(np.identity(2**n_qubits),dtype=T.cfloat).to(device)
f(theta,ro_train).backward(gradient=theta)
print(theta.grad)
```

**Output**
None

UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations.
print(theta.grad)

**Expected**
0

Comment: I ran your code and was not able to reproduce the error. i got 'tensor(-0.0002)
'. What version of pytorch are you using. i have many problems with the most recent 'stable' versions. i recommend using version 1.7.1+cu101

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0.dev20210119 and working on jupyter notebook, window10. It does not works to me

Comment: I updated as 1.7.1+cu101 but it produce error like below                                    
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 with CUDA capability sm_86 is not compatible with the current PyTorch installation.
The current PyTorch install supports CUDA capabilities sm_37 sm_50 sm_60 sm_61 sm_70 sm_75 compute_37.
If you want to use the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 GPU with PyTorch, please check the instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

  warnings.warn(incompatible_device_warn.format(device_name, capability, " ".join(arch_list), device_name))

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce your error and got the following output.

```
UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed.
```

What that means is that you're trying to get the gradient of a variable that isn't a leaf in the computational graph. Since theta is the result of the .to(device) operation in the line `theta=T.tensor(1,dtype=T.float,requires_grad=True).to(device)` it is an intermediate variable and not a leaf. To force pytorch to compute the gradients of non-leaf variables you have to call their .retain_grad().
Just add `theta.retain_grad()` after the line I mentioned.
You can read more about it in [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/grad-attribute-of-a-non-leaf-tensor-being-accessed/82313) in the pytorch forum